# Is it possible to query by Uuid using Prisma?

Tags: typescript, postgresql, prisma

I'm attempting to populate a postgresql db based off of a remote Api's response every xx min.

The script would be calling the Api on a determined interval, iterating over the response from the Api, upserting the data into the database for the relevant record.

This is the code that I've been starting with just to try to get the where statement functioning.

```
let world = await prisma.world.findFirst({
    where: {
        Uuid: some_variable.WorldId, //UUID4 string
    }
})
```

but it's giving me the below error

> Type '{ Uuid: string; }' is not assignable to type 'WorldWhereInput'.
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'Uuid' does not
> exist in type 'WorldWhereInput'.

Given the below schema, is it possible to query by the `Uuid` field, or even upsert using the Uuid, and is it better to create an Int based Id when storing the remote data, instead of relying on the Uuid from the remote Api, as shown in the schema.

There are going to be relationships, to other models that haven't been defined, yet that also if that matters?

**schema.prisma**

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgres"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model World {
  Id                    Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  Uuid                  String  @unique @db.Uuid
  Name                  String
  IsSurvival            Boolean @default(false)
  IsHumanOnly           Boolean @default(false)
  Fuel100LLBasePrice    Int
  FuelJetBasePrice      Int
  JobsBaseBonus         Int
  JobsMaxBonus          Int
  ShortName             String
  EnableEconomicBalance Boolean @default(false)
}
```

**example response**

Comment: Have you run `prisma generate` after changing the schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as I understand you don't want to create UUID's yourself but use the external ones?

If that assumption is correct I think you don't need `@db.Uuid`, as it indicates that prisma should rely on your database to create Uuids:
[Check their documentation about it.](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#override-default-value-behavior-for-supported-types)

Your `where` looks correct to me, what is the type of `some_variable.WorldId` ? Is it really string?

Another problem I could think of is that you forgot to migrate, after adding the Uuid field to the database.

Comment: Correct, ideally I'd like to use the external ones as Id's within relationships, too. I will try your suggestions out when able, thank you.

Comment: Your suggestion resolved the asked question, I am curious if its possible to use the external Uuid as the pk/fk though.

Comment: I think that should be possible. As long as you can trust that your external source delivers unique slugs. But rely on something external is in the most cases a bad idea.

You can change somethink like:
```id Int @id @default(autoincrement())```
to:
```slug String @id```